# await in custom Redux middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux

How would I use await inside a custom middleware.

```
const customMiddleware= (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  if(action.type === 'Start'){
    const apiResult = await FetchFromApi;
  }
  const result = next(action);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **async** before action

```
const customMiddleware= (store) => (next) => async (action) => {
  if(action.type === 'Start'){
    const apiResult = await FetchFromApi;
  }
  const result = next(action);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: greate!
It save my time to search.

Answer (score 1):

Simply turn the innermost function into an `async` function, and then you can use `await`.

```
const customMiddleware = (store) => (next) => async (action) => {
  if(action.type === 'Start'){
    const apiResult = await FetchFromApi;
  }
  const result = next(action);
  return result;
}
```

I don't know what you're intending this middleware to be used for. Perhaps you have a usecase where you want to write your own like this, in which case go for it. But if you're just looking to do general purpose async stuff, consider using redux-thunk, redux-saga, or redux-observable to handle your asynchronous actions.